# Package retrieving error is occurred while installing Chocolatey packages

Tags: chocolatey

I've installed Chocolatey with nuget.exe and tried to download Ruby package.

However, installation is failed with the message `The package was not found with the source(s) listed.`

```
C:\Users\nblizz>sudo choco install ruby -y
Chocolatey v0.10.14
Installing the following packages:
ruby
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Error retrieving packages from source 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/':
 The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
ruby not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (c:\ProgramData\chocoportable\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - ruby - ruby not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.
```

I've tried this on Command prompt running as administrator mode. What is the problem?
The install command of Ruby package is `choco install ruby` and I typed it as it is.

Comment: Based on the output you are seeing, I am not clear on why this package isn't being found.  I have just run the same command, and it works as expected.  Do you have any proxy in play that might be preventing access to chocolatey.org?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark I don't know why, but it works well after changing my internet connection from Wi-Fi to wired internet.

Comment: This sounds networking related to me, but keep in mind that the public Chocolatey repo has issues sometimes and I've seen us get the `An unexpected error occurred on a send` error before. We use a private repo at work for our packages now.

Comment: I face the same issue with upgrade commands. i can open the URL for the packages in the browser. I have not tried what happens if I connect to wired net but that does not sound right.

Comment: @EnDelt64 The exact same thing is happening here. Chocoley only works on my wired network. Did you investigate this further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in my case - i was not using the correct name of the package. Ensure that you are using the full name and if you are getting this error perhaps validate it on the website (https://chocolatey.org/packages/)

Answer (score -4):

Run `cmd` as administator then:

`choco install elixir`